# Option plan promised not on offer letter

Tags: job-offer, united-states, recruitment, tech-industry

During the interview and text exchanges the company's manager (who I will be reporting to) mentioned several times that I "would be rewarded with option plan", and I was happy about it.

But when I receive their offer and NDA paperwork several hours after his promise, I find no clause on option plan. Shall I point this out? Shall I directly ask them to include it in the offer or send me details in a separated file? Is it offensive to point this out?

Will they later substitute part of my annual salary with options that can be potentially valueless? It is my first time promised with options so I am not familiar with the hidden rules involved.

Comment: Can you add some details about what an option plan is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're in a negotiation. If there was a verbal promise that isn't accounted for in the offer letter, I would recommend you speak up. It's mostly likely just a common oversight, but there may subversive reasons it's not present.

At any rate, the offer letter should very specifically detail out all compensation and benefits to be provided. If you don't see the package you were promised, you will do better to speak up and ensure that it's present. It is never offensive to point any of this out.

Negotiate for the value you bring, then hold the company to putting it in writing. It's not about being offensive or mean. Business is business.

Answer (score 3):

> Shall I point this out?

Yes.

> Shall I directly ask them to include it in the offer or send me
> details in a separated file?

Either would work. Just explain that it appears to be missing from the offer letter. Explain that you'll be happy to either sign a corrected offer letter, or sign the offer letter and a separate letter concerning the option plan.

> Is it offensive to point this out?

It's never offensive to point out issues that you feel are important.

Answer (score 1):

You should politely ask where it states you are entitled to the option plan, and all details on the plan. Maybe there is an attachment, or it's something that is voted on each year again, or only starts after 2 years on board.